# How can I ignore null columns when iterating through a table? (Javascript only)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am iterating through a table using a for loop in Javascript.
Due to how the table was originally design the header row is technically a row in the table. I have a loop that suppose to scan all the rows in the table and insert each row in a database. The problem is it is trying to insert the "null" row into the database. Another issue I am having with this is loop is the rows are all techanically a clone of the original row I have with the original row technaically be hidden with some css but it still exists in the table you can't access it either. So if my table has one row the loop is seeing three rows (the header row, the original row that is clone, and the actual table row I am typing everything into and using) and trying to insert all three which returns a sql error because two of those rows aren't compatible with what I am doing. What I am trying to do is if the row is null or has null values it should be skip over and move on to the next row.

How can I get it to skip/ignore

```js
$(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function () {
  var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
  if (answer) {
    // * Table variable
    var table = document.getElementById("steptable");
    // ! Since there is an extra th element in the table (the headers) the loop has to start from 1 and not zero
    for (var i = 1, row; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
      // * Condition to prevent
      if (Name === null) {
        continue;
      }

      // * iterate through rows
      // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
      ObjType = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Name = table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Business = table.rows[i].cells[4].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Project = table.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Deployer_Candidate =
        table.rows[i].cells[6].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Description = table.rows[i].cells[7].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      console.log(row);
      console.log("ObjType = " + ObjType);
      console.log("Name = " + Name);
      console.log("Business = " + Business);
      console.log("Project = " + Project);
      console.log("Deployer_Candidate = " + Deployer_Candidate);
      console.log("Description = " + Description);
    }

    // * Loop that will run the sql statement for each row in the table
    for (var i = 1; i < selectTkt.length; i++) {
      console.log("This is working");

      if (testSelect != "NEW") {
      }
      // * else display service message
      else {
        console.log("Service Cancel");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="steptablecontainer">
                        <div id="steptable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
                            <table id="steptable" class="compact cell-border no-footer dataTable row-border"
                                role="grid">
                                <thead id="recordTableHead">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <!-- * Names For Each Container *-->
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 25px; max-width: 25px;"></th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 50px; background-image: none; max-width: 25px;">Record</th>
                                        <th class="componentellipsis sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Component"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Type</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 125px;">Name</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Test"
                                            style="width: 100px; max-width: 50px;">Business</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dev"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Project</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 150px; max-width: 125px;">Deployer Candidate</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 400px; max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Description
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->

                                <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display: none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
                                    <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth">
                                            <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record"
                                                value="0">
                                                <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Record intializing *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>

                                        <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
                                        <div id="container">
                                            <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
                                                <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
                                                    <option value="TP">TP</option>
                                                    <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
                                                    <option value="Package">Package</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </div>


                                        <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
                                            <p>
                                                <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
                                                <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder=""
                                                    class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
                                            </p>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name"
                                                placeholder="" style="display: none;">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
                                                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
                                                    CorporateFinancialServices
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
                                                <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
                                                <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
                                                <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
                                                <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
                                                <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
                                                <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
                                                <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck"
                                                placeholder="">
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c
                                                    21000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c
                                                    20000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c
                                                    11000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1
                                                    (wm52a/b/c
                                                    40k/41k/42k)</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Description *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
                                            <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder=""
                                                class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;"
                                                </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <!-- * Add & Remove buttons *-->
                            <div class="btn-group2">
                                <div id="addRemoveButons" class="dt-buttons" style="visibility:hidden">
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn2" title="Add new record" style="display: inline-block;">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn" title="Add new record">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordRemoveBtn" title="Remove last record" style="display: none">
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]null values?

Comment: Your code snippet throws an error. Please start by fixing that.

Comment: Sorry about that the Javascript should be fix now

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question clear enough, but why can't you just start iterating the rows at row 3?

Comment: I try that and it doesn't work for me. It might skip the header row but it does not skip the invisible original row. I need a way to skip the row if it is null

Comment: If the row is there, it is not null. You seem to be checking the name before you set the name, so if the name from the previous iteration is null, it'll continue. I would check the name *after* setting the variables, and only run the SQL-loop if it's null then.

Comment: I am confused so you are saying   // * Condition to prevent
      if (Name === null) {
        continue;
      }
 should be after the variables are set but before the console logs? Why would I run the SQL loop if the name is null? The goal is to get only the inputs that have values in them. Sorry I guess I am a little lost on your logic for the rows.

Comment: Your `if (Name === null)` line should go *after* `Name = table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector(".vcheck").value;` because otherwise, you are checking a previous row. Also, you need to check that `Name` is actually a `null` for empty rows. It could be just an empty string.